# Is there a way to force a screen size to the mobile header in a WordPress theme with CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to find a way to force a specific screen size to the mobile header view. Now, when I go to my webshop on an Ipad, you see the desktop screen, which I don't want. I want the mobile/tablet view but it seems like the screen is slightly too big for this.

How can I accomplish this with CSS?

Thanks in advance.

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJGoX.png)
[This is what it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmAeR.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you code your CSS add a media query i.e.

```
    /*DESKTOP SIZE DISPLAY*/
    
    @media screen and (min-width : 815px){
        
        .className{
            
            position: fixed;
            top:0;
            height:40px;
            width:100%;
             
        } 
}
```